# Issue with leaf tensor error during backprop

Tags: pytorch, tensor

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
weights = []
bias = []
z = []
act = []
lr = 0.01
shapes = [6, 400, 400, 400, 2]
x = [[1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0,0,0], [0,0,1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,0,0], [0,1,1,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,0,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1], [1,1,1,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,0],[1,0,0,1,1,1],[1,1,0,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,0,0],[1,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,1,0], [1,0,1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,1,0],[1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0,1,1],[0,1,1,0,1,0],[1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0]]
x=torch.Tensor(x)
y=torch.tensor([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1])
batch_size=len(x)
for i in range(len(shapes)-1):
    weights.append(torch.ones((shapes[i], shapes[i+1])))
    bias.append(torch.zeros((shapes[i+1],)))
    z.append(torch.zeros((batch_size, shapes[i+1])))
    act.append(torch.zeros((batch_size, shapes[i+1])))
    
parameters = [weights, bias]

for p in parameters:
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        p[i].requires_grad = True

for i in range(100):
    z[0] = x @ weights[0] + bias[0]
    act[0] = torch.sigmoid(z[0])
    z[1] = act[0] @ weights[1] + bias[1]
    act[1] = torch.sigmoid(z[1])
    z[2] = act[1] @ weights[2] + bias[2]
    act[2] = torch.sigmoid(z[2])
    z[3] = act[2] @ weights[3] + bias[3]
    act[3] = torch.sigmoid(z[3])
    
    cost = F.cross_entropy(act[3], y)
    print(cost)
    cost.backward()    
    for p in parameters:
        for i in range(len(weights)):
            p[i] = p[i] -lr * p[i].grad
print(cost)
```

This is my code. I keep getting UserWarning: The .grad attribute of a Tensor that is not a leaf Tensor is being accessed. Its .grad attribute won't be populated during autograd.backward(). If you indeed want the .grad field to be populated for a non-leaf Tensor, use .retain_grad() on the non-leaf Tensor. If you access the non-leaf Tensor by mistake, make sure you access the leaf Tensor instead. See github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/30531 for more informations. on line weights0 = weights0 - lr * weights0.grad. Please help, I have tried everything I can and am pulling my hair out

I tried to retain graph, retain grad of non leaf tensors, i tried adding retain grad on the leaf tensors. Everything

Comment: in-place updates break autograd tracking